# VS Code installing a specific .NET SDK version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, q#

Is there anyway you can get VS Code to install a specific `.NET SDK` version that you have used in an old application?

I have an old `Q#` app that uses SDK version `3.1.416` with `netcoreapp 3.1` but I don't wanna install these on my new laptop that has `.NET SDK 6.0.300` so I am wondering if there is maybe a way to get VS Code to install these exact versions, so I can still run my old app?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is [VSCode Remote Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers). I currently have more than 4 different versions of .net core and the likes. All thanks to legacy project maintenance.